# Is using one dimensional map array faster than 2d?

Tags: java

Am making tile Map based game, Where i use one dimensional array to store map,
Which makes stuff bit more difficult. I wanna know if two dimensional array is any slower or not, So if not, I won't bother making it harder for myself in future projects.

EDIT:
Array Size is somewhere like 1 million.
and what am doing with that array is that am grabing it's values
and place textures on screen according to those values.

Comment: That entirely depends on what you do with those arrays, their size and so on

Comment: You know what they say about premature optimisation.

Comment: If you need a 2d array, just use a 2d array.

Comment: I don't need to, i will just consider that it's mostly okay to use 2d arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2D array in Java is an array of arrays. For comparison, the 1D array `int[] a = {1,2,3,4}` is stored as 4 contiguous integers in memory, as such:

```
|1|2|3|4|
```

while a 2D array `int[][] b = {{1,2},{3,4}}` is stored as such:

```
   +--------------+ 
   |              |
|.|.|   |1|2|    |3|4|
 |       |
 +-------+
```

I.e., b[0] and b[1] each points to an array of 2 integers somewhere in memory.

Thus b[0][0] requires that a reference be read and followed to access the element while in the 1D case, a[0] can access the element directly.

The other performance issue is that the subarrays are not necessarily stored contiguously in memory and therefore the whole 2D array would not be loaded in the processor cache in one go. Depending on the size of your array and how you processed the data this can make a big difference in performance.

However, in most cases, these performance differences would be small enough to not affect the performance of your program and **you should choose the structure that makes your program easier to read and to reason about**.

My advice would be to go with the 2D array if it makes your program simpler; you can always optimize this later.

You could also encapsulate the array in an abstract data type that hides the way that the array is accessed (I.e., it could be using either a 1D or 2D array with an access method such as getValue(x, y) with the method internally managing the array addressing).

Comment: Although I generally agree with your argumentation, I recently had a performance issue with a math-heavy application representing matrices as two-dimensional arrays, typically `double[3][3]`. Profiling showed that creating 2D arrays was dominating the runtime. Changing to 1D gave a big performance boost.

Comment: Like I wrote, accessing elements in a 2D array is bound to be slower than in a 1D array. It then depends on how compute-heavy your specific application is.

Comment: It wasn't accessing, it was creating the arrays.

Comment: This should be made bold: **"you should choose the structure that makes your program easier to read and to reason about"**. The day your main performance bottleneck is the fact you've used a 2d array instead of a 1d array, your code will be in a very very good shape ;)

Comment: I'm editing my answer to follow your suggestion @sp00m as I agree that's the central idea of my answer

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff that makes sense, since a 3x3 2D Array requires the creation of 9 arrays in total, while an 1D Array only requires one. But you have to differ between creation and access. *Most of the time* you would have only one or few creations but many accesses. Sure, the access of an 2D Array is a bigger performance hit than accessing a 1D Array, but not such a big hit as the creation.